# Shipping Application that uses google Cloud Vision API

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

Google authenticates the request to its Cloud API by using a JSON File stored in the local machine.I need to set the path to the JSON File to use the library

```
 System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", @"C:\Users\admin\Downloads\vision.json");
```

So if i'm shipping the application,will it be necessary to ship the JSON as well?
Won't it pose a security risk?

***UPDATE 1:***

```
 System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", @"vision.json");
 client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm using the code below to create credential from file.I'm planning to encrypt this JSON file; host it in the server.Download it,decrypt it in the client side and create credencial from it.

My question is without storing the JSON locally in disk,can i store it in memory and create credencial from it?

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("vision.json").CreateScoped(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultScopes);
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(
ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(),
credential.ToChannelCredentials());
client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);
```

Comment: This is an application you want to ship to end users, rather than it being a server-side application, yes? If so, you need to consider which Google Cloud Project you want to be billed for the Vision requests. While you *could* create a service account which only has access to the Vision API, that still runs the risk of a user misusing either your application or the account in order to make more requests than expected, at your expense. If you want the user to use their own GCP project, then you'd probably want the application to have some way of asking where their credentials are.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes.it will be a windows desktop application.I will enforce restrictions myself.The question is .. where to store the JSON?

Comment: Wherever you can do so securely, I guess. Note that you don't *have* to use the default application credentials - you could fetch the service account details from another server for example. See https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/faq.html#how-can-i-use-non-default-credentials-for-grpc-based-apis for the current way of using non-default credentials - it's a little ugly, but we're working on improving it. But fundamentally that's still going to expose the service account to your users, which does come with a security risk.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay..Thanks....

Comment: @JonSkeet Isn't it possible to hardcode the API Key in code rather than supplying the JSON file and setting the environment variable?

Comment: You can load credentials from memory rather than from a file, sure, e.g. `GoogleCredential.FromStream`. But it's got to be full account credential, *not* an API key.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you guide me to an example.

Comment: Not right now I'm afraid, but I'd strongly recommend editing your question with what you've tried and what goes wrong. The link from before shows how to create a channel when you've got a `GoogleCredential`, and if you've got the data in memory you can use `GoogleCredential.FromStream` or `GoogleCredential.FromJson` (if you've got a string) to create the credential. If you can show the exact situation you're in and what's wrong, that'll make it much easier to help you than trying to cover every possibility. I would again consider *very carefully* the security implications though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please see the update.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm meant to be taking from the update - that's still just setting the environment variable. It's not using `FromStream` or `FromJson`, or loading the credentials directly as per the link I included before.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please see update #3

Comment: And again, yes - `GoogleCredential.FromJson` will allow you to do it from a string (which is in memory) and `GoogleCredential.FromStream` will allow you to do it from *any* stream, including a `MemoryStream`.